# How to implement `CSS` nested rules in `JSS`?

Tags: css, material-ui, jss

I would like know how to work with `css` class-nesting in [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) or in `JSS` in general?
I am trying as below.

```css
    card: {
      cardHeader:{
         marginTop:"30px"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 30):

For JSX like

```
<div className={classes.card}>
  <div className={classes.cardHeader}></div>
</div>
```

you can use:

```js
card: {
  '& $cardHeader': {
      marginTop: 30,
  }
}
```

Targeting nested classes can be helpful if you override default JSS styles in Material UI components.

Comment: how about a rule like `'&-postfix'`? The only way to reference this was using `\`${classes.card}-postfix\``. Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 18):

It would be the same as writing CSS(not to be confused with SCSS or SASS). JSS transforms all js to pure CSS pretty much all CSS properties should work here as well.

```
card: {
 '& .cardHeader': {
   marginTop: 30 // px is default
 }
}
```

You will need to setup up plugins for this thanks @ricovitch for pointing out this. For default you can check this[jss-preset-default](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss-preset-default).
For react you can simply use [react-jss](https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss) which has built-in default presets.

Comment: This does not work if you don't configure jss-nested plugin

Comment: Have been using this with https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss which does it out of box

Comment: Appreciate your help! Worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Material-UI includes a set of JSS plugins documented here : https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#plugins

In these plugins set there is jss-nested which allows for nested rules : http://cssinjs.org/jss-nested/

But in your sample code there is actually no need for nested rules, as you just need one : "cardHeader"